# jQuery click event just for touch, for all others hover

Tags: jquery, touch, detection

I tried to modify my jQuery code, to use the "hover" event just on default desktop devices and take the "click" function just on touch devices. For reason, that there is a better usability by separating them.

I posted my whole code in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syZC6/

```
 $(document).ready(function(e){
              $("header").hover(function() {   
                  if ($('#expandMenu').is(':visible'))
                  {
                      $('#menubar').removeClass('menu-active');
                      $('#switcher').removeClasse'switcherOpen');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $('#menubar').addClass('menu-active');
                      $('#switcher').addClass('switcherOpen');
                  }

                  $('#expandMenu').slideToggle( "fast");
               });          
                });
```

Maybe there is a solution, like I have done it before:

```
$(window).width() < 900 ? "true" : "false",
```

But it just detects the current width on window load, and not the kind of device…

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the event based on your conditions

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/e2fc7/

```
   var touchscreen;
   if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 300px)").matches) {
       touchscreen = true;
   } else {
       touchscreen = false;
   }

   var evt = touchscreen ? 'touchstart' : 'mouseenter';

   $("header").bind(evt, function () {
       if ($('#expandMenu').is(':visible')) {
           $('#menubar').removeClass('menu-active');
           $('#switcher').removeClasse 'switcherOpen');
   } else {
       $('#menubar').addClass('menu-active');
       $('#switcher').addClass('switcherOpen');
   }
   $('#expandMenu').slideToggle("fast");
   });
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks pretty good, but are you sure it works? I copied your code into the jsfiddle and there was no more action...

Comment: Sorry just checked and edited. I replaced `hover` with `mouseenter` and `on` with `bind`. I works as expected now.

Comment: @Vector what is "(max-width: 300px)" used for and why 300px?